# How to solve call trace produced by security_ops_task_setrlimit() with bind

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, security, redhat, bind

I have a machine with CentOS 5.9 and VMware installed.

Currently I am using BIND 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6 (default shipped with distribution).

When I restart the machine, I can see this message on screen just when the named service is started:

```
Starting named: You need to implement a remote task_setrlimit in your security module and call it directly from this functionWARNING: at security/security.c:51 security_ops_task_setrlimit()

Call Trace:
[<ffffffff8012eeeb>] security_ops_task_setrlimit+0x87/0x96
[<ffffffff8009dc0a>] do_prlimit+0xd7/0x1d2
[<ffffffff8009ed53>] sys_setrlimit+0x36/0x43
[<ffffffff8005d29e>] tracesys+0xd5/0xdf
```

This error doesn't seem affect to bind, the service works fine, but I would know what produces the warning error and how to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This message is harmless and can be ignored.](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhelv5-list/2013-January/msg00009.html) It is a note to kernel developers.

Red Hat also published a [statement to this effect](https://access.redhat.com/node/290593) in its KB (subscribers only, boo).

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this message at console, adding this to /etc/rc.local :

echo 3 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk

Comment: This seems to address the symptoms, more than the problem.  One generally doesn't turn off logging to resolve errors being logged...  I'd hope that sometime the responsible kernel developer might issue a patch for that.